# How to use IntelliJ debugger to print logs?

Tags: intellij-idea, logging, intellij-13

How can I print logs in the console without actually adding sysout or logs to the code in IntelliJ IDEA debugger?

Answer (score 5):

youtube link [intellij debugger logging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0OOgyIfJsU)

> Step 1 set a break point

[image: Set a break point]

> step 2 right click the debug point and uncheck suspend - you should see breakpoint turn yellow.

[image]

> step 3 check evaluate and log and enter your logger statement

[image]

> Step 4 debug your program to see the logs printed using intellij debugger and not using loggers in code

[image]